# Windows Photo viewer and manager for people who suffer from paranoia (schizophrenia)

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I'm looking for a Photo viewer and manager that doesn't do anything with analyzing, tagging, identifying content in pictures. This is for someone who has schizophrenia, and who suffers from paranoia. Windows Photos does all kind of things that she doesn't like, like analyzing and tagging pictures. It results in her thinking that her pictures are shared on the internet, which is very problematic for her. I've tried to unset most of these things, but now and again new things pop up, like with the latest big Windows update - the tagging.

She uses Windows 10. With Ubuntu or macOS it wouldn't be a problem as both don't have these issues and have good photo apps, but currently I'm stuck with Windows. Buying a Mac is not an option, and Linux doesn't have some of the software she uses. And if you think the logical option would be to go to Linux and deal with it - logic doesn't work here. Privacy settings are a problem for some things, but not for others. Again, there's no logic, and if I would start to stress this, it would result in much more problems for her and for me as I need to fix them.

I don't mind paying something like $40 to get rid of these problems.

Another requirement is a clean interface, a Photos like experience with maps to browse folders. It may have cloud options, if it can work without it and won't nag the user. Complicated options are OK, if they are hidden and don't clutter the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/)?

I can't think of any image viewer that is as offline-based* as it is and more feature full.

*Meaning that it doesn't have the feature to upload images to Social Media etc.

Check a list of features [here](https://www.irfanview.com/main_what_is_engl.htm).

On top of all the above features it's free for personal use.

Comment: That was my first thought too - upvote Maybe also http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm, but in both cases I would contact the programmers first to be 100% certain about those auto-features